Как поменять go.mod, чтобы go build не просил выполнить go mod tidy
Мне нужно сменить версию go в go.mod с 1.22.3 на 1.22 Или написать так:
module main

go 1.22

toolchain go1.22.3

req...

После чего запустить go build, но при ручном изменении go build выдаёт: go: updates to go.mod needed; to update it: go mod tidy
ВАЖНО: я не могу использовать 1.22.3, мне нужен именно 1.22 для статического анализатора, иначе он не будет работать.
Я пробовал менять руками или ставить различные флаги при сборке. Игнорирования этого требования просто нет. Изменить файл просто так я тоже не могу, требование go mod tidy все равно появляется.

Я ещё слабо разбираюсь в Go, но может быть надо поменять строку toolchain go1.22.3 на toolchain go1.22?
